# MySQL returning multiple results for a single emoji

Tags: mysql, utf-8, emoji, utf8mb4

I'm observing some strange MySQL behavior for VARCHAR fields that contain a single emoji. The connection, database and column are all utf8mb4 encoding and collation.

There's a table called `categories` with `id` and `title` fields. There's three rows, with titles of ,  and .

When I run a query looking for a row with the title , I get all the other rows with single emojis as well, as if MySQL is treating them as the same characters.

[image: Query for credit card emoji returning all other single emoji rows]

The expected behaviour should be that only the row with  is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`; the older collations treat Emoji as equal.

Comment: For a peek into MySQL 8.0, with Unicode 9.0, see `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` in [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html).

Answer (score 2):

The *collation* determines whether two characters are considered to be equal or not.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

If you want only an exact binary match, you might want to specify a binary collation.

Some syntax examples here for `latin1`.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Indeed, the problem seems to be with `utf8mb4_general_ci`, whereas `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` works with emoji as expected.

Comment: @maknz -- something wrong with your test; unicode is not adequate; you need unicode_520; see my answer.

Comment: Using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` fixes the problem, what does 520 do that unicode itself doesn't?

Comment: @maknz:  The **`_520_`** in the collation name indicates that this is an implementation of version 5.2.0 or the Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA). The names without `_520_` implement an earlier version (UCA 4.0.0). MySQL also has collations that are backwards compatible with collations implemented in earlier versions of MySQL

Comment: Okay, I guess I'm just stumped as to why the regular `unicode_ci` fixes my example above, when it's not.. meant to? Are there any specific cases where `unicode_520_ci` will work better than `unicode_ci`, or is it just better practice?

Comment: Ah.. actually, it's probably because I'm using Percona's MySQL fork (5.6). Can't find any literature on any Unicode differences to MySQL, but that could be it.

Comment: I have not heard of the forks differing in collations.  `520` distinguishes some characters that used to be treated equal.  Emoji is one set of such.  Among "letters", several are noted in [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html), such as `ae=Æ=æ < az` instead of `ae < az < Æ=æ`.  See also `Ď,Ł,Ø`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've marked your answer as correct given it's the best solution for emoji support.